# Sending BufferedImage over server to another java client

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am attempting to send a BufferedImage over a socket sever to another client. Ill post my code below. When I run the server and the connect to the server with the sending client, and receiving client, everything just sits there. The server shouldn't even be receiving anything unless it has already printed "name is attempting to connect to: " which it doesn't it just sits there. I don't know why it doesn't do anything at all.

Client that sends: http://pastebin.com/X4z55Hdp

Client that receives: http://pastebin.com/MB9qEyGy

Server Source that sends and recieves:

```
package core;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import utilities.Tools;

public class Node implements Runnable {

private String name;
private Socket socket;
private boolean isApp;

public Node(Socket s, String name) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setSocket(s);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Socket getSocket() {
    return socket;
}

public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);
            if (in.readLine() != null) {
                // Tools.log("[INPUT] " + in.readLine());
                String i = in.readLine();
                if (i.contains("set name ")) {
                    String n = i.replace("set name ", "");
                    Tools.log("Changing " + name + " to " + n);
                    this.name = n;
                    if (n.contains("_app")) {
                        this.isApp = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    String toFind = name + "_app";
                    if (isApp)
                        toFind = name.replace("_app", "");
                    Tools.log(name + " is attempting to connect to: "
                            + toFind);
                    for (Node n : Server.nodes) {
                        if (n.getName().equals(toFind)) {
                            Tools.log(n.getName() + " found, sending data");
                            ObjectOutputStream outToNode = new ObjectOutputStream(
                                    n.getSocket().getOutputStream());
                            ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(
                                    socket.getInputStream());
                            BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) inFromClient
                                    .readObject();
                            if (img != null) {
                                outToNode.writeObject(img);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use your stream in 2 different wrappers (BufferedInput and ObjectInput). If the error still occurs after situating that problem, post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the problem

Answer (score 1):

The BufferedImage must be serialized. You can convert the image in to a byte array and once it reads the byte array, convert it back in to an image.

Answer (score 1):

The sender is undoubtedly getting a `NotSerializableException` when calling `writeObject()` with a `BufferedImage`, because `BufferedImage` doesn't implement `Serializable.` Therefore you can't get one from a `readObject()` call either. You'll have to turn the `BufferedImage` into bytes for sending, and back again when receiving. Have a look at `javax.imageio` for one way to do this.